# ios Titanium modules installing : No Titanium folder in Library/Application Support folder

Tags: ios, titanium, osx-mavericks, titanium-alloy

I've installed the Titanium on the OS Maverics.

Try to install PayPal module for the Titanium.

But it is no Titanium folder in Library\Application Support.

What can cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titanium modules **on a Mac** are usually located in
`~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules`
That is within the user folder of your disk: 
`/User/[Username]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules`

Comment: Thank you. ! But I should to put it in the User/Username/Library/... or just in System/Library/... ?

Comment: Keep it as it is. Titanium decides where to put your modules on install, so if your modules reside within the user folder, put your custom modules in the corresponding folders, `../modules/iphone` for iphone modules and `../modules/android` for android modules. Titaniums own modules, like ti.map and facebook, should already be there. As soon as you added a module, it should be available in tiapp.xml. If not, you might have to restart Titanium.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just put the module inside the `modules/iphone` or `modules/android` directory of your application.

Comment: no, I use Alloy. There's no modules derictory in it.

Comment: Using Alloy or not doesn't matter. Create the directory, and you can place modules inside of it, just like with a vanilla Titanium application. Or just place the zips in the app directory and run a build; it'll get unzipped for you in to the proper directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the folder in `Macintosh/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Titanium`.
Normally the `Library` folder is hidden, to unhide the folder you can check [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25451517#25451517). It worked for me.